# Python: How to update an attribute programmatically?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm looking for a way to update an attribute programmatically (especially when inside an `update()` function of an SQLAlchemy class)

```
def update(self, **kwargs):
    for kwarg in kwargs:
        setattribute(self, kwarg, kwargs[kwarg])
```

This does not seem to work, neither this:

```
def update(self, **kwargs):
    for kwarg in kwargs:
        self[kwarg] = kwargs[kwarg]
```

Comment: [`setattr(self, key, value)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing, but this doesn't look like a good idea to me. You usually want to [keep data out of your variable names](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`setattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
def update(self, **kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        setattr(self, key, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

`kwargs` is a `dict`, you can iterate on its keys and values with `items()`:

```
def update(self, **kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        setattr(self, key, value)
```